# Reducing the number of parameters a function takes in python

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I have the following structure in my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import <something>
.
.
.
from modules import *
from optparse import OptionParser

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = self.get_argument()
        self.set_argument(parser)

    def my_args(self):
        parser = OptionParser(usage='usage: %prog [options]', version='%prog 1.0.0')
        parser.add_option('-t', '--test', action='store_true', dest='test', default=False,
            help='Help of test.')
        .
        .
        .
        return parser

    def set_args(self, parser)
        options, args = parser.parse_args()
        params = dict(test=options.test, ..., arg100=options.arg100)
        self.start(**params)

    def start(self, **params):
        print params


    def ...:
        ...
    .
    .
    .

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

I want to run start for getting parameters and its values for using in other functions. but:

```
TypeError: start() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I use kwargs for passing them?

What is best way in order to use parameters in `start`.
I am really new with `kwargs`.

Comment: How are you calling the `start()` method? If I use the `start()` method you've written above, it doesn't error, just prints out an empty dictionary.

Comment: pardon, yes. you are right. how can I use kwargs for passing them?

Comment: start is define to take kwargs or keyword arguments, because you put the ** in front of params, then in set_args you define params but you pass test, which is not even declared and you do not pass any keyword params. I don't know if you have another `test` declared somewhere. You might want to fix those problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
class Test(object):

    def a(self):
        p = {"a":1, "b":2}
        self.start(**p)

    def start(self, **params):
        print(params)


t = Test()
t.a()
```

result is:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

`**kwargs` allows a function to take keywords arguments, and constructs a dictionary

```
In [3]: def g(**kw):
...:     print(kw)
...:     

In [4]: g(a=1, b=2, c=3)
 {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

If you want to pass a dictionary to the function, you'll need to unpack the dictionary, like this:

```
In [5]: d = dict(e=42, f=65)

In [6]: g(**d)
   {'e': 42, 'f': 65}
```

See http://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/, or the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Comment: How this code can be changed and use kwargs for passing arguments?

Comment: please see update, The error is `TypeError: start() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` when I call `self.start(**params)`

Comment: What happens when you print `params` before calling `start`?